# Android notification not announced by TalkBack

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, talkback

My Android app creates a notification.  The notification is correctly displayed.  However, TalkBack does not announce the notification, as it does, for example, when I receive new email.  If I display all the notifications and scroll through them, TalkBack will read the text of my notification.  However, I want it to automatically announce the notification when it is raised.

```
String notificationText = getResources().getString(R.string.notifyText);
String notificationTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.notifyTitle);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setContentText(notificationText)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

Of the various methods of [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html), setContentText() determines what is displayed visually, but [setTicker()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setTicker%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) is the method that determines what, if anything, is read by TalkBack.

Comment: With android 8 (sdk 26), this did not work. What android version did you test?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely will need to inform TalkBack that you want to interact with it by making your app accessible.  [Here is the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html) on making apps accessible.

There is also a setting on views that you can enable so that it knows that the view is important for accessibility however I don't think this directly applies to your notification issue.

```
android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
```

You might also try using a [AccessibilityEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html) instead of sending out just a normal notification (or potentially both).  This way the system knows that the event is specifically for accessibility services and may be what TalkBack reacts to.

```
AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
if (manager.isEnabled()) {
    AccessibilityEvent e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
    e.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT);
    e.setClassName(getClass().getName());
    e.setPackageName(context.getPackageName());
    e.getText().add("some text for TalkBalk to announce");
    manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(e);
}
```

Also keep in mind that some versions of TalkBalk will only read the text if you provide a `View`

```
if (manager != null && manager.isEnabled()) {
        final AccessibilityEvent e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
        view.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(e);
        e.getText().add("some text for TalkBak");
        parentView.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(view, e);
    }
```

Comment: But TalkBack works everywhere else in the app, other than with the notification.

Comment: Notifications are handled differently since they are sent from your app but processed by another process in the OS.  Try the additions I added to my answer (specifically trying to dispatch an `AccessibilityEvent` which may be what TalkBalk expects to react to.  I think you will have better luck with this approach.